# ASP.net core how to return result list from a get statement

Tags: asp.net-core

I just followed along on some tutorials and am able to route a get statement. I have a db named `InterDB` and I want to return all results for `intchNumb = IntchNbr`. What do I do if I have to return multiple rows of data I want to return instead of just `FirstOrDefault`

```
    [RoutePrefix("interchange")]
    public class InterchangeController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("Notes/{intchNumb}")]
        public InterDB Get(String intchNumbr)
        {
            using (InterchangeEntities entities = new InterchangeEntities())
            {
                return entities.InterDB.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IntchNbr == intchNumbr);
            }
        }
    }
```

I originally tried using  `return entities.InterchangeNotes.All(e => e.IntchNbr == intchNumbr);`  but the All extension doesn't return data only a boolean. I will also need to change return statement to

`public List<InterchangeNote> Get(String intchNumbr)`

If you could point me to some documentation that would be appreciated.

Comment: Try entities.InterchangeNotes.Where(e => e.IntchNbr == intchNumbr);

Comment: I tried that while changing return type to ```IQueryable<InterchangeNote>``` and that gives exception  ```"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."```

Answer (score 0):

after switching FirstOrDefault to Where I was simply missing toList():

`return entities.InterDB.Where(e => e.IntchNbr == intchNumbr).toList();`